# Calling dir in cmd prints out: "Volume in drive C has no label."

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

I run a Windows 10 System and whenever I call `dir` on cmd I get this message:

```
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume serial number: 5A4F-9364
```

German original:

```
Volume in Laufwerk C: hat keine Bezeichnung.
Volumeseriennummer: 5A4F-9364
```

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: This is not an error; you don't need to fix anything. But if you want, you may give your drive a label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like it says: Your `C:` drive doesn't have a label, or name. You can assign one with the `label` command:

```
Creates, changes, or deletes the volume label of a disk.

LABEL [drive:][label]
LABEL [/MP] [volume] [label]

  drive:          Specifies the drive letter of a drive.
  label           Specifies the label of the volume.
  /MP             Specifies that the volume should be treated as a
                  mount point or volume name.
  volume          Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
                  mount point, or volume name.  If volume name is specified,
                  the /MP flag is unnecessary.
```

or in the Properties panel of the drive:

[image]

Back in the old days, we used to give floppy disks a name. Hard drives can have one as well, but most of the time no one cares. Explorer shows such drives as “Local Disk (C:)”, and `dir` has the somewhat scarier message.

Comment: Thanks. I settled for Nuck Chorris.